# Extending from trait where each instance's singleton type is type parameter

Tags: scala, inheritance, types, singleton-type

Suppose I want every instance of an `Item` to be a `SourceOf` that `Item`, and every `SourceOf` a subtype of `Item` to be a `SourceOf` all instances of that subtype. This seems like a natural way to do it:

```
object Demo {
  trait Item extends SourceOf[this.type]

  trait SourceOf[+A <: Item]
}
```

Obviously this won't work, since `this` refers to the `Demo` object, not to each `Item` instance. (I've tested it.)

How can I tell the Scala compiler that every `Item` is a source of itself? It should be possible to get the compiler to deduce stuff like:

- "Every source of (all) farming implements is a source of the specific farming implement you're looking for."
- "If you're looking for the source of a farming implement, and you already have the farming implement, then you need look no further."

Here's an example (written to ignore type erasure for brevity):

```
trait FarmingImplement extends Item
object TheRototiller extends FarmingImplement

def findSource(item: Item, seq: Seq[SourceOf[_]]): Option[SourceOf[item.type]] =
  seq.collectFirst {
    case src: SourceOf[item.type] => src
  }

val sources = Seq(   // example: possible sources of TheRototiller
  new SourceOf[Nothing] { override def toString = "Wrong source" },
  new SourceOf[FarmingImplement] { override def toString = "Right" },
  TheRototiller /* also right */ )

val got = findSource(TheRototiller, sources).get
println(got)  // Should print "Right", since the second source in `sources`
              // is the first match.
```

I want the type of `got` be `SourceOf[TheRototiller.type]`, not `SourceOf[Item]`. But mainly I want Scala's type system to do the work of determining whether a `SourceOf` matches a given `Item` or category of `Items`.

Comment: It sounds like you need mutually recursive types. Is that even possible in Scala? I think not, since you don't have something like `and` in SML/OCaml (i.e. a way to say "don't start looking for the types I just told you to look for until you finish processing the next declaration"), but I'm not enough of a Scala wizard to say. Interesting question.

Comment: Suppose that `TheRototiller` wasn't included in `sources`. In that case, what would you want the result (and result type) of `findSource(TheRototiller, sources).get` to be?

Comment: According to ""If you're looking for the source of a farming implement, and you already have the farming implement, then you need look no further.", shouldn't the implementation of `findSource` be:  `def findSource(item: Item, seq: Seq[SourceOf[_]]) = item`  ?

Comment: @MilesSabin The result would still be the second source. (The second source appears earlier in the Seq. I'll rewrite the example to make this clearer.) The type of the result would still be `SourceOf[TheRototiller.type]`, since that's determined statically.

Comment: @Chirlo No, what I mean by "already having it" is having it in the list of sources. Passing `TheRototiller` to `findSource` means "Where should I look for the rototiller?" Possible answers are: "Ask that object", "Here it is", and "I don't know". (`TheRototiller` is really a tag, not the rototiller itself, but I'm trying to keep the question narrowly focused.) I'm hoping that Scala's type system can manage the category relationships, since they're isomorphic to inheritance in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

At least, this gonna solve your problem with passing `this`:

```
object Demo {

  trait C[+A]

  trait Item extends SourceOf {
    type T = C[this.type]
  }

  trait SourceOf {
    type T <: C[Item]
  }
}
```

Example (you'll have to compare `T`s instead of `SourceOf`s here):

```
scala> val i = new Item{}
i: Demo.Item = $anon$1@c70cb4c

scala> implicitly[i.T =:= i.T] //compile-time type equality check
res4: =:=[i.T,i.T] = <function1>

scala> val i2 = new Item{}
i2: Demo.Item = $anon$1@1f26ac06

scala> implicitly[i.T =:= i2.T]
<console>:18: error: Cannot prove that i.T =:= i2.T.
              implicitly[i.T =:= i2.T]
```

If you need to check types in runtime (as you've shown in example with pattern matching) - I would recomend to use `TypeTag`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Demo {

  abstract class C[+A: TypeTag] 

  trait Item extends SourceOf {
    type T = C[this.type]
  }

  trait SourceOf {
    val tag = typeTag[this.type] //just to access
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> val i = new Item{}
i: Demo.Item = $anon$1@3b2111b0

scala> val i2 = new Item{}
i2: Demo.Item = $anon$1@4e7bb48a

scala> typeTag[i.T].tpe =:= typeTag[i2.T].tpe //runtime type-equality check
res9: Boolean = false

scala> typeTag[i.T].tpe =:= typeTag[i.T].tpe
res10: Boolean = true
```

Finally, implementation of `findSource`:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Demo {

      trait Item extends SourceOf 

      trait SourceOf {
        type I = this.type
        val tag = typeTag[I]
      }

      def findSource(item: Item, seq: Seq[SourceOf]): Option[item.I] =
        seq.find(_.tag.tpe =:= item.tag.tpe).asInstanceOf[Option[item.I]]
}
```

Examples:

```
scala> val i = new Item{}
i: Demo.Item = $anon$1@1fc2899d

scala> val i2 = new Item{}
i2: Demo.Item = $anon$1@5f308abb

scala> val ri = findSource(i, Seq(i, i2)).get
ri: i.I = $anon$1@1fc2899d

scala> implicitly[ri.I =:= i.I]
res2: =:=[ri.I,i.I] = <function1>
```

`asInstanceOf` is used (it's safe to do here) because `Seq` looses path-dependent type in compile-time and we used runtime-check to match types, so no way to find it for compiler. However, Shapeless2's `HList` + `Selector` based implementation might be more pure.

Comment: Very educational! I hadn't known about using `implicitly` in the REPL to inspect inheritance relationships. That got me reading some good stuff about Scala types and implicit resolution, which I now am finally able to understand. I especially like the simplicity of this approach: just stick `this.type` into a type parameter of a phantom type. Does the `asInstanceOf` cause a run-time check? I keep thinking that the compiler ought to be able to deduce this stuff (even though the run-time penalty is surely too small to care about).

Comment: @BenKovitz and you're right, it's able but not for `Seq`s that kill any "personality" of `Item`s, like some bad cult :). This is why I use `asInstanceOf` to return it back, to unbrainwash them. I believe, no run-time check takes place here as after JVM-erasure this cast is becoming `Option` to `Option` so actually no cast at all. Anyway, I'm gonna provide `Shapeless`-based solution as `HList` saves the personality, I just don't have enough time yet.